ant5 form: mismatch in form.setFieldsValue and values got from Select input
I have an AntD5 form where the input is a select dropdown.
In the parent component i set the intial Values that come from the database using an useEffect. The instructions are an array of objects [{id, text}]
useEffect(() => {
 form.setFieldsValue({
      ...specType,
      instructions: specType.instructions?.map(instr => instr.name) || [],
    });
  }, [specType]);

Then I have my form with the Form.List, since i can add more than one instruction
 <Form.List name="instructions">
              {(fields, { add, remove }, { errors }) => (
                <>
                  {fields.map(({ key, ...field }, index) => (
                    <Form.Item
                      required={false}
                      className="mb-4"
                      key={key}
                      {...formItemLayout}
                      label={index === 0 ? t('common.instructions') : ''}
                    >
                      <Row wrap={false}>
                        <Col flex="auto">
                          <InstructionsSelect
                            {...field}
                            validateTrigger={['onChange', 'onBlur']}
                            rules={[
                              {
                                required: true,
                                whitespace: true,
                                message: t('common.requiredField')
                              }
                            ]}
                            mode="default"
                            form={form}
                            noStyle={false}
                          />
                        </Col>
                        {fields.length > 0 ? (
                          <Col flex="none">
                            <DynamicDeleteButton onClick={() => remove(field.name)} />
                          </Col>
                        ) : null}
                      </Row>
                    </Form.Item>
                  ))}
                  <Form.Item {...formItemLayout}>
                    <Button type="dashed" onClick={() => add()} block>
                      <Space style={{ justifyContent: 'center' }}>
                        <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faPlusCircle} />
                        {t('spec.addInstruction')}
                      </Space>
                    </Button>
                    <Form.ErrorList errors={errors} />
                  </Form.Item>
                </>
              )}
            </Form.List>

and finally the Instruction Select component, where I retrieve all the instructions from the db and pass them as options to the andD Select component
const InstructionsSelect = ({
  onChange,
  mode = 'multiple',
  form,
  ...props
}) => {
  
  const { data: options = [],  } = useQuery({}); // query to the db to get the list of instructions
  
  console.log('INST', form.getFieldValue('instructions'));

  return (
    <Form.Item {...props}>
      <Select
        mode={mode}
        optionFilterProp="label"
        options={options
          .filter(e => !form.getFieldValue('instructions').includes(e._id))
          .map(({ text, _id }) => ({
            value: _id,
            label: text
          }))}
        filterOption={(input, option) => option?.label?.toLowerCase().indexOf(input.toLowerCase()) >= 0}
        allowClear={allowClear}
        onChange={onChange}
      />
    </Form.Item>
  );
};

My problem is in the filtering the already chosen instructions (the ones that i sent initially, and the ones that i select )
If I log the
form.getFieldValue('instructions'), 

i get a mix of texts (for the instructions set in the useEffect) and ids for the newly selected ones.
If in the useEffect i change to
form.setFieldsValue({
      ...specType,
      instructions: specType.instructions?.map(instr => instr.id) || []})

the
form.getFieldValue('instructions') 

prints ids omogenously but in the pre-filled fields now i see the ids and not the text.
Is there a way to handle the filtering properly?

You have set id in useEffect but filtering the options doesn't make sense. You have to include an option to see proper text in Select otherwise antd will show value (id) as fallback

I see, but I was asked to remove the options that ara already chosen. So what should I answer? Is it not possible then?

I'm not sure about why you were asked to do this. Even if they want to ignore the selected options, you still need to pass the selected options but make it disabled. You may need to discuss it with your team...

well, it was a reasonable request to me, under a user perspective. If you can choose from a list, e.g. apple, kiwi, orange, cherry, if I choose apple and kiwi and open again the select i don't want to see them (and pick them up again, maybe). Then i understand the problem of removing the option

You only want to hide options from dropdown when instructions values are set in form in useEffect or dropdown should always hide selected option from options list while still showing selected option label in Select?
